# Redis master-slave "connection lost" error

Tags: docker, redis, redis-sentinel

I have two docker machines:

```
$ docker-machine ls
NAME           ACTIVE   DRIVER       STATE     URL                         SWARM   DOCKER    ERRORS
redis-master   *        virtualbox   Running   tcp://192.168.99.100:2376           v1.10.1   
redis-slave1   -        virtualbox   Running   tcp://192.168.99.101:2376           v1.10.1
```

I am trying to deploy master/slave redis replication to those machines, so on each of them I run REDIS container + SENTINEL container and run `SLAVEOF` command on master redis instance. Everything works fine at first, but after some time (1-2 minutes) master prints `# Connection with slave 192.168.99.101:6379 lost.` message in log and slave logs `# Connection with master lost.` and infinitely (without success) tries to resync with master.

REDIS version I use is `3.0.7` (also using sentinel shipped with redis).

Here is MASTER log (redis and sentinel logs): http://pastebin.com/raw/MvwCTeEu

Here is SLAVE log (redis and sentinel logs): http://pastebin.com/raw/vV6e3utK

sentinel.conf:

```
port 26379
dir /tmp
sentinel announce-ip <SENTINEL_IP>
sentinel monitor mymaster <MASTER_IP> 6379 2
sentinel down-after-milliseconds mymaster 30000
sentinel parallel-syncs mymaster 1
sentinel failover-timeout mymaster 180000
sentinel announce-port 26379
```

redis.conf: http://pastebin.com/raw/dqFYzTwz (it's actually default REDIS config , except `repl-backlog-size` which I've increased to `100mb` to check if it wont help but it did not).

This is strange issue because at first replication/syncing works fine at first but, as I said, after 1-2 minutes master-slave connection is lost. During this time no redis/sentinel command are executed on any instance. I just start 4 containers and leave them for 1-2 minutes...

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this issue?